# Why won't React Native Maps show my user location?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-maps

Totally baffled.

I have React Native Maps implemented.
I have the `showsUserLocation` prop set to true.
In IOS/Xcode i added the key/value to info.plist

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>a description lives here and stuff</string>
```

And through adding a .gpx file i was able to simulate a users location.

But in *Android* i cannot get showsUserLocation, showsMyLocationButton, showsCompass props to work.

Is there a setting on the emulator or in An/Studio somewhere that permits this?

MapView:

```
<MapView
    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
    followsUserLocation={true}
    showsUserLocation={true}
    showsMyLocationButton={true}
    showsCompass={true}
    toolbarEnabled={true}
    zoomEnabled={true}
    rotateEnabled={true}

    style={{flex: 1}}
    region={{
    latitude: 51.4718,
    longitude: -0.0749,
    latitudeDelta: 0.01,
    longitudeDelta: 0.01
    }}
>
    { markers.map((each, i) => {
        console.log('each: ', each);
        return ( 
            <MapView.Marker
                key={i}
                title={each.title}
                description={each.description}
                coordinate={{ latitude: each.latitude, longitude: each.longitude }}
                />
        )
    }) }
</MapView>
```

I've also attempted to give the IOS simulator lat/lng but Debug > Location > Custom Location will let me edit *EITHER* the Lat *or* the Long. Not both. Very strange.

Comment: Did you find solution for this @NewbieAid?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem in Android. So, I made a custom showUserlocation. Where I made a button

```js
              <View >
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.find_me()} >
                        <Image style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }} 
                            source={require('../resources/img/icon_pin_dark.png')} />

                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
```

to render this function.

```js
find_me() {

        this.show = true
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {

            this.region = {
                latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
            }
            this.userLocation = {
                latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                longitude: position.coords.longitude
            }
          
            console.log('yeah')
          

          

        }, 
        (error) => {
           
            console.log("Location provider is not enable")
        },
        
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    _onMapReady = () => this.setState({marginBottom: 0})

.........

<MapView
    style={{flex: 1, marginBottom: this.state.marginBottom}}
    onMapReady={this._onMapReady}
```

and your inital marginBottom should be 1.

This is finely worked for me.